# I want to know how calculate that start date(datefield) is less than always from end date(datefield) in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a form in which i add two dates

1. Start date
2. End Date

I want to know how i validate that the selected start date is always less than end date(actually an expiry date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do some thing like this to compare the dates,

```
trace(validateDate(new Date(2008, 5, 1), new Date(2008, 6, 1)));  


protected function validateDate(date1:Date, date2:Date):Boolean
{
    return (date1.time < date2.time);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You look some thing like this.Try This function:

```
public function compare (Start_date: Date, End_Date : Date) : Number
{
    var Start_date1 : Number = Start_date.getTime ();
    var End_Date1 : Number = End_Date.getTime ();

    if (Start_date1 > End_Date1)
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Small sample

```
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
            import mx.events.CalendarLayoutChangeEvent;

            private function compareDate():void {
                var fromDateFormat:String = DateField.dateToString(new Date(fromDates.selectedDate), "YYYY/MM/DD");
                var toDateFormat:String = DateField.dateToString(new Date(toDates.selectedDate), "YYYY/MM/DD");
                var todayDateStr:String = DateField.dateToString(new Date(), "YYYY/MM/DD");

                var fromDate:Date = DateField.stringToDate(fromDateFormat, "YYYY/MM/DD");
                var toDate:Date = DateField.stringToDate(toDateFormat, "YYYY/MM/DD");
                var todayDate:Date = DateField.stringToDate(todayDateStr, "YYYY/MM/DD");


                if(ObjectUtil.dateCompare(todayDate , fromDate) >= 0 && ObjectUtil.dateCompare(todayDate , toDate) <=0){
                    Alert.show("Valid");
                }else{
                    Alert.show("InValid");
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:DateField id="fromDates"/>
    <mx:DateField id="toDates"/>

    <mx:Button id="checkValidity" click="compareDate()"/>

</mx:Application>
```

or

check the below link for validation

http://www.iamboredsoiblog.eu/flexfiles/start_end_date_check/srcview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use two dataFields and desable the end dateField date less than start dateField

you can do like this

```
<mx:DateField id="stDate"/>
<mx:DateField id="endDate" selectableRange="{{rangeStart: stDate.selectedDate}}"/>
```

from above you need not to compare the end date with start date... because dated less than start date will not be enable in end dateField..